# show str(...) as table in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a library or function for r-markdown to show the structure of a dataframe as a table? Something similar tot the output of `str(myDataFrame)` but as a pretty formatted r-markdown table?

For example the following output should be shown as at least the colums holding the feature names, and the datatypes. Some example values would be nice but are not required.

```
str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

str uses cat so there is no way to transform it into a pretty data.frame to print. But you can mimic its functionalities to create one, and then pass it to your favorite rmarkdown table formatter (kable, pander, etc.):

```
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
data.frame(variable = names(mtcars),
           classe = sapply(mtcars, typeof),
           first_values = sapply(mtcars, function(x) paste0(head(x),  collapse = ", ")),
           row.names = NULL) %>% 
  kable()

|variable |classe  |first_values                             |
|:--------|:-------|:----------------------------------------|
|mpg      |numeric |21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1           |
|cyl      |numeric |6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6                         |
|disp     |numeric |160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225             |
|hp       |numeric |110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105              |
|drat     |numeric |3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76         |
|wt       |numeric |2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46     |
|qsec     |numeric |16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22 |
|vs       |numeric |0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1                         |
|am       |numeric |1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0                         |
|gear     |numeric |4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3                         |
|carb     |numeric |4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1                         |
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I was hoping there is already a convenient function hidden in one of those various libraries but it doesn't seem so. There was one thing I had to change to run this code: instead of the class function, I had to use the typeof function as shown in the answer by R. Schifini below.

Comment: Thanks for updating

Comment: Did any of you deal with the problem of row names showing up? I'm running a similar piece of code as the one in this answer (I just changed the dataset and I'm using map functions from the purrr package) and, for some reason, the names of the each row keeps showing up as if were my first column.

Comment: @MasonBeau you could use `data_frame` instead of `data.frame`

Comment: I'll try this and I'll let it be known here if it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m = sapply(mtcars, typeof)
```

Result:

```
> m
     mpg      cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec       vs       am     gear     carb 
"double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double" "double"
```

Or with `lapply`:

```
m = data.frame(lapply(mtcars, typeof))
```

Result:

```
> m
     mpg    cyl   disp     hp   drat     wt   qsec     vs     am   gear   carb
1 double double double double double double double double double double double
```

Comment: Thank you. This perfectly works for me in combination with the answer above.